# Neo4j- finding person whose mother doesn't have siblings and father has siblings

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a weird problem with my query. If I write something like this:

```
MATCH (parentOfMother: Person_kol)-->(mother: Person_kol)-[:MOTHER]->(p: Person_kol)<-[:FATHER]-(father: Person_kol)<--(parentOfFather)-->(:Person_kol) WHERE NOT (:Person_kol)<--(parentOfMother)-->(mother)
RETURN distinct(p.idPerson)
```

It gives me a person, whose mother's mother doesn't have any kids except the person's mother, but person's mother's father has a lot of kids.

The query works fine if I write it like this:

```
MATCH (mother: Person_kol)-[:MOTHER]->(p: Person_kol)<-[:FATHER]-(father: Person_kol)<--(parentOfFather)-->(:Person_kol) WHERE NOT (mother: Person_kol)<--()-->()
RETURN distinct(p.idPerson)
```

Why is it? I don't see any particular difference in queries.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the fact that in the first query, some nodes are revisited in the path /  predicate combination.

I would write your query as follows

```
MATCH (p:Person_kol)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((p)<-[:MOTHER]-()<-[:FATHER|MOTHER]-()-[:FATHER|MOTHER]->())
      AND
      EXISTS( (p)<-[:FATHER]-()<-[:FATHER|MOTHER]-()-[:FATHER|MOTHER]->())
RETURN p
```